# Can I use a JQuery plugin under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license in a commercial webapp?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

if a JQuery plugin is released under the [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license, can it be used as part of a closed source commercial web application which is not redistributed, just accessible on the web?

Answer (score 1):

The license says:

> Notice — For any reuse or distribution, you must make clear to others the license terms of this work. The best way to do this is with a link to this web page.

So just make a link to the website and you'll be fine.

Comment: It also says "you may distribute the resulting work only under the same or similar license to this one". And one could easily consider using it in a webapp as some kind of distribution of a resulting work.

Comment: yeah, so if you make a comment in your code containing the link to the website, that'll do. I'm no lawyer, so cant judge how the legal mumbojumbo works with these licenses.

Comment: Also I'd contact the original author and hint to him/her that CC is ill-suited for source code and it is actually discouraged to use it.